# How to position cursor from textbox1 to textbox2 in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two `textboxes` in my web application for login page,  `RegNo` and `Address`. Now I want that if the page loads then cursor should be on `RegNo` textbox . After entering `RegNo` it must goes to `Address` after press `Enter`. How to do This?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   </head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="RegNo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button  CssClass="sCancel" ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Close"  onclick="btnCancel_Click" Width="84px"  /> 
        <asp:Button CssClass="sUpdate" ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update"  onclick="btnUpdate_Click" Width="84px" style="margin-left: 0px"/> 
        <asp:Button CssClass="sAdd" ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Add" Width="84px"  onclick="Add_Click"   />  

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you only need to change focus to next textbox? After which event should it change? For example when userid reach a `specific length`? Or when user press `Enter`?

Comment: When User press enter

Comment: i Have updated my code

Comment: check again my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I assume what you ask is how to change focus from `userid` to `password` and you don't need to move cursor itself.

Note that there is no need to do this in *server side*. You are able to simply do this in *client side* with *JQuery*. If you are not familiar with *JQuery* see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) to understand how to add *JQuery* to your *client side* code.

Now I assume code in your client side is something like this:

```
Username: <asp:TextBox name="userid" id="userid" /><br>
Password: <asp:TextBox name="password" id="password" />
```

I will provide two examples with JQuery for this, in first example the focus will jump to *password* when user press **Enter**:

```
$('#userid').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#password").focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

In next example we change focus to *password* when *userid* reaches a specific **lengths**. for example 6:

```
$('#userid').keydown(function (e) {
    if ($("#userid").val().length > 5) {
        $("#password").focus();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

It should work in your code:

```
<head runat="server">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#RegNo').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#Name").focus();
                    return false;
                }
             });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:TextBox ID="RegNo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>

        </div>
     </form>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the need of value 13 in condition?

Comment: Every key on keyboard has a `keycode` and 13 is `keycode` of `Enter` key. For more information read here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp

Comment: @DivyaDiya add `return false;` It prevents to enter invoke submit. See update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#RegNo').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#Name").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $('#Name').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#Address").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            $('#Address').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#Add").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });


        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by the use of Tabindex Property of  TaxtBox.

First, You set the Tabindex=1 to Textbox1 
then,set the Tabindex =2 to TextBox2 and so on..

By this when your page is load then it look tabindex of control which is less it focus on that.

Thanks

Comment: And if you hit enter it jumps to next textbox?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="RegNo" runat="server" Text="" Tabindex="1">                          <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text="" Tabindex="2">             <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" Text="" Tabindex="3">

Comment: @masoud keshavarz I have tried your code. But After pressing Enter the cursor move to textbox2 ("Name") but immediately jump to my previous page without any entry in a name field.